# Changing stepper Motor speed

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I have stepper motor, that I want to control his speed. How is it possible?

I am using an Arduino UNO.

```
for (i = 0; i<400; i++)       // Iterate for 4000 microsteps
{
    digitalWrite(StepPinB, LOW);  // This LOW to HIGH change is what creates the
    digitalWrite(StepPinB, HIGH); // "Rising Edge" so the easydriver knows to    when to step.
    delayMicroseconds(500);     
}
```

Comment: Did you check Arduino's reference pages? https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Stepper?from=Tutorial.Stepper

Comment: More info, please. What are you trying and what results did you have?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can control the speed of your stepper motor. You can either decrease the delay time between each step or you can adjust the size of the step the motor takes.

Decreasing the delay time is straightforward, just lower the delayMicroseconds and the stepper motor will have an increased step rate. However, there is a limit to how small the delay can be.

Adjusting the size of the step(i.e. full step, half step) requires altering your circuitry for the motor driver and depends of what kind of driver you're using. Just google your motor driver model and try finding a wiring diagram to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

1>> Decrease the stepping time.(will work upto 1 millisecond as far as i remember).

2>> YOU can change the ovarall speed with half stepping, full stepping or microstepping(the more smaller is the step slower it will be.) do special care with types of stepping as it can also affect your torque.